Fill amchart5 series fill template after chart init
This code works great when series are built but need to perform this after chart init
series.fills.template.setAll({
  fillOpacity: 0.2,
  visible: true
});


this is working for me but visual changes occured only after zoom or resizing the window
this.chart.series.each(function(chartSeries) {
const y = chartSeries.fills.template;
y.set('visible', true);
y.set('fillOpacity', 0.2);
});
